# Query (of class "PhabricatorDaemonLogQuery") overheated: examined more than 10 raw rows without finding 1 visible objects

Tags: daemon, phabricator

I got an error as Query (of class "PhabricatorDaemonLogQuery") overheated: examined more than 10 raw rows without finding 1 visible objects. 
Phabricator was running fine. But don't know how this error comes. I restarted the daemons. And the phabricator start to run again normally. Actually I want to know what this error means.